# PHP login not working as intended

Tags: php, mysql, session

I got a problem in my login, that when I first open my browser I need to do 2 times login to get redirected to my index. After that I can logout and login and all works fine.

My login code:

```
    <?php
include "connect.php";

session_start();
if (isset($_POST['user_login'])) {
    $state_on = 1;
    $state_off = 0;
    $user = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username=:name AND password=:pword AND state=:s");
    $user->bindParam(":name", $_POST['username']);
    $user->bindParam(":pword", $_POST['password']);
    $user->bindParam(":s", $state_on);
    $user->execute();
    if ($user->rowCount() > 0) {
        $row_user = $user->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $user_id = $row_user['id_user'];
        $user_session = $row_user['session_id'];
        $user_lvl = $row_user['id_lvl'];
        $update_session = $conn->prepare("UPDATE users SET session_id =:idsession WHERE id_user=:iduser");
        $update_session->bindParam(":iduser", $user_id);
        $update_session->bindParam(":idsession", session_id());
        $update_session->execute();
        $_SESSION['session_id'] = $user_session;
        $_SESSION['id_user'] = $user_id;
        $_SESSION['id_lvl'] = $user_lvl;

    header("Location: index.php");

//        echo 'login = SUCCESS!';
    } else {
//            echo 'login = FAIL!';
    }
}
```

and here is my session.php that I include in index. php

```
session_start();
include "connect.php";

$login_session = $_SESSION['session_id'];
$login_user = $_SESSION['id_user'];
$login_nvlseg_user = $_SESSION['id_lvl'];

if (!isset($login_session)) {
    $conn = null;
    header('Location: login.php');
}
try {
    $session_sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE session_id=:session";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($session_sql);
    $stmt->bindParam(":session", $login_session);
    $stmt->execute();
    if ($stmt->rowCount() == 0) {
        session_unset();
        $conn = null;
        header('Location: login.php');
    }
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
    // 

   echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Yeah you have to verify first (before if) if the session is set.. (logged in)

Comment: I had tried that with if(session_status() ..... but that seems to not solve my problem... I need to login 2 times aswell...

Comment: Are you getting "SUCCESS" echo on first login ?

Comment: yeah, i can get it...

Comment: Interestingly a search on SO for "PHP login not working" gives me 2,552 results, perhaps one of those will be able to help you solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

You have to check if the user is logged before the check for $_POST.

Would so something like this in front of it:

```
  session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['id_user']) {
  // redirect
  header("Location: index.php");
}
```

Comment: thanks for the fast reply, but that dosen't work.
Like when I first click submit I got to login.php again and fields get cleaned (username and password), but if I refresh I got redirect to index.php...

Comment: you have to check for existing session user_id before displaying the form

Answer (score 1):

You need to put the `session_start` on top of your script like this:

```
<?php
# session_start() should be on top when you using sessions
session_start();
include "connect.php";


if (isset($_POST['user_login'])) {
    $state_on = 1;
    $state_off = 0;
    $user = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username=:name AND password=:pword AND state=:s");
    $user->bindParam(":name", $_POST['username']);
    $user->bindParam(":pword", $_POST['password']);
    $user->bindParam(":s", $state_on);
    $user->execute();
    if ($user->rowCount() > 0) {
        $row_user = $user->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $user_id = $row_user['id_user'];
        $user_session = $row_user['session_id'];
        $user_lvl = $row_user['id_lvl'];
        $update_session = $conn->prepare("UPDATE users SET session_id =:idsession WHERE id_user=:iduser");
        $update_session->bindParam(":iduser", $user_id);
        $update_session->bindParam(":idsession", session_id());
        $update_session->execute();
        $_SESSION['session_id'] = $user_session;
        $_SESSION['id_user'] = $user_id;
        $_SESSION['id_lvl'] = $user_lvl;

    header("Location: index.php");

//        echo 'login = SUCCESS!';
    } else {
//            echo 'login = FAIL!';
    }
}
```

I hope this solved your issue!

Comment: thanks for the fast reply, but I still got the same "error" :/

Comment: @JPeter make sure you are using `session_start();` in your `index.php` too, on top of your script.

Comment: in my index.php I had included session.php where I made session_start() and work with session_id to only use one session for user